# Autocomplete IE & Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Hy,

I need little help.
I use jquery Autocomplete and it only works on Chrome. Any IE or Firefox doesnt show a list.
here is my code:

```
  $(function() {

$( "#project" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: "fetch.php",
  focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
    return false;
  },
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
    $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
    $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
    return false;
  },
})
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

});

I have the #project field in a modal. Is that the problem?
I searched on stackoverflow but nothing helps me.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you tried already? What are console / debugging outputs of your affected browsers?

Comment: Could you check console output from IE (F12 opens dev tools)? Maybe there is an error message that would help us/you.

Comment: it is all the same.. in network it shows fetch.php?term= . in chrome the same in ie. without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
$(function() {
$("#project").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: "fetch.php",
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#project").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#project").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#project-id").val(ui.item.value);
            $("#project-description").html(ui.item.desc);
            return false;
        },
    })
    .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
            .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

It looks like the handles have changed in newer versions of jQuery: [1.9](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changed-naming-convention-for-data-keys) & [1.10](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#removed-item-autocomplete-data-use-ui-autocomplete-item)

It looks like the sample used [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) is using the old handles, that no longer work correctly!

Comment: thanks, but its not working. is that because i have that in a modal? on header i have a searchbox an it works only in the search box. in modal it show nothing.

Comment: @joergi1988 I have made a change to the code above. Try that. If not, then we would need to look into it more with use of modal, possibly related to the `z-index`.